# LocaleChangeInterceptor not working

Tags: spring, localization, internationalization

I'm trying to have my web application multilingual, so I added LocaleChangeInterceptor to my servlet.xml. Here is the relevant code:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="mii.root.i18n.mii-messages" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="language" />
</bean>

<bean id="mappingHandler" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
    <property name="interceptors">
       <list>
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
       </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And I have links like this:

```
<a href="?language=fr">
<a href="?language=hr">
<a href="?language=de">
```

MessageSource works fine, if I change defaultLocale in localeResolverBean the language changes. But when i click on links there is no change in locale.
I'm using springframework 2.5.6. 
I really don't know what I did wrong, I went through a lot of tutorials and examples, there are no errors logged and the most bizarre thing is that it had been working like a charm for a few weeks since i configured it for the fist time and a week ago it suddenly stoped.

Comment: Apparently I was missing mappings fot the mappingHandler, so I've put 

    <property name="interceptors">
       <list>
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
       </list>
    </property>

inside my already existing SimpleUrlMappingHandler I was using for navigation and view resolving.
How did it work before I don't know, most likely there was some kind of sorcery in play.